Android Here SDK: How can I make a vehicle profile/settings to prefer back roads - mostly?
Using the Here SDK lite edition, is it possible to make it generate routes for vehicles with smaller engines? Get it to prefer the back roads over roads above 35 mph etc.
ScooterOptions vehicleOptionsObject = new ScooterOptions();
                vehicleOptionsObject.routeOptions.alternatives = 3;
                if ( settingsPrefs.getString("routing_type", "fastest").equalsIgnoreCase("fastest") ) {
                    vehicleOptionsObject.routeOptions.optimizationMode = OptimizationMode.FASTEST;
                    vehicleOptionsObject.routeOptions.trafficOptimizationMode = TrafficOptimizationMode.TIME_DEPENDENT;
                } else {
                    vehicleOptionsObject.routeOptions.optimizationMode = OptimizationMode.SHORTEST;
                    vehicleOptionsObject.routeOptions.trafficOptimizationMode = TrafficOptimizationMode.DISABLED;
                }
                vehicleOptionsObject.engineSizeInCubicCentimeters = 50;
                vehicleOptionsObject.routeOptions.speedCapInMetersPerSecond = (double) Utils.convertMilesToMeters(settingsPrefs.getInt("routing_pref_max_speed", 35));

                //vehicleOptionsObject.avoidanceOptions = avoidanceOptions; <- breaks scooter option
                routingEngine.calculateRoute(
                        waypoints,
                        vehicleOptionsObject,
                        (routingError, list) -> {
                            processRouteData(list, routingError, inter);
                        });

I've been trying various vehicle means and options. Yet, even a "speedCapInMetersPerSecond" of 1, will still produce a 35 mph on average route for my area. This is not the route I would use if I was on my scooter. I'd cut through the back roads and only use the 35 mph road if necessary. I wish "OptimizationMode.LONGEST" was possible.
